# swagger error: No route matches the supplied values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, swagger

I'm building a little test web API app using swagger.
When I try to run an HttpPost to create a new "Driver", I'm getting the above error.  Here's what the controller looks like in part:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using FireApp.Models;

namespace FireApp.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DriverController : ControllerBase
{

    private static List<Driver> drivers = new List<Driver>();
    private readonly ILogger<DriverController> _logger;

    public DriverController(ILogger<DriverController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddDriver(Driver driver)
    {
        drivers.Add(driver);
        return CreatedAtAction("GetDriver", new { driver.Id }, driver);
    }
```

Here's what the model looks like:

```
namespace FireApp.Models
{
    public class Driver{
        public Guid Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}= "";
        public int DriverNumber {get; set;}
        public int Status {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Here's what the Post looks like in Swagger:

[image]

Based on the Request Body that is auto created for me (with default values), it seems that it's finding the right method because the Post needs a Driver object passed in.
Not sure what else I should be asking myself / checking in the code.

Comment: I think i found the bug.  The first parameter i'm passing the to the CreatedAtAction() method doesn't match the name of the actual method "AddDriver".  I tried to change it to match and now it works.

Comment: Try adding `[ApiController]` attribute to your controller (class) and `[FromBody]` to your POST method, e.g. `public IActionResult AddDriver([FromBody] Driver driver)`.
edit: [links to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#controllerbase-class-2)

Comment: To your comment: the first parameter of `CreatedAtAction` should return the methods name of your GET (by id) route, so "GetDriver" (or what ever you named it) should be correct. For less problems when refactoring, use `CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetDriver), new { myEntity.Id }, myEntity)` - note the use of `nameof`.